# Airflow user creation

Tags: python, authentication, airflow

I am using Airflow version 1.8.2 and set up couple of Dags.Everything running as expected .I have admin user created for airflow web server access.But for other teams to monitor their job we can't provide this admin user So I tried to create a different user from the UI '/admin/user/'.
But only the following fields are available .No options to provide roles or password etc.
[image]

Does anyone faced the same issue or I am doing some wrong thing .How to create role based users So that I can tag some specific dags to those teams

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As of Airflow 1.10, there is an `airflow create_user` CLI: https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#create_user.

It supports roles and passwords:

```
airflow create_user [-h] [-r ROLE] [-u USERNAME] [-e EMAIL] [-f FIRSTNAME]
                    [-l LASTNAME] [-p PASSWORD] [--use_random_password]
```

Update: As of Airflow 2, this has been rolled into `airflow users create`: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#create_repeat1

```
airflow users create [-h] -e EMAIL -f FIRSTNAME -l LASTNAME [-p PASSWORD] -r
                     ROLE [--use-random-password] -u USERNAME
```

Comment: Note that the `airflow create_user` (soon to become `airflow users --create` or similar) is only for the RBAC based UI, which isn't enabled by default in 1.10

Comment: I just tried the latest version of airflow and created the user.But not able to find a way to logging in .My url always going back to the admin view and it never ask for any user logging even after I logged out.Is there any thing I am missing here .I changed ```authenticate = True
filter_by_owner = True
rbac = True``` .Is there anything missing to enable full RBAC thing in 1.10?

Answer (score 10):

The user models in Airflow are currently simplistic and (as of at least 1.9.0) there is no way via the UI to set passwords.

The approach I use is the following python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import getpass
import sys


def create_user(opts):
    from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
    from airflow import models, settings

    u = PasswordUser(models.User())
    u.username = opts['username']
    u.email = opts['email']
    u.password = opts['password']

    s = settings.Session()
    s.add(u)
    s.commit()
    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('email')
    parser.add_argument('username', nargs='?', help="Defaults to local part of email")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not args.username:
        # Default username is the local part of the email address
        args.username = args.email[:args.email.index('@')]

    args.password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter new user password: ")
    confirm = getpass.getpass(prompt="Confirm:  ")

    if args.password != confirm:
        sys.stderr.write("Passwords don't match\n")
        sys.exit(1)
    create_user(vars(args))
```

This versoin doesn't support changing passwords as we haven't needed it yet

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Using this script I have created the user .But the user have same privileges as the admin user.Is there any way to create a normal user and later we can provide specific dag access to that user?

Comment: No, Airflow 1.9 and 1.10 doesn't yet have per-DAG permissions. That should be coming in the next release.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .But the airflow  docs says it supports multi tenancy .But the fact is that we are not able to share the credentials across the team as all the users have the same admin privilege .Our idea is to have one cluster and sharing that across multiple teams to monitor their DAG's .

Comment: The situation isn't great in 1.9 as you say. The next non-point release (i.e. _not_ 1.10.1) should add per-dag access control.

Comment: I just installed airflow 1.10.2 and RBAC feature is working when I tested basic DAG operations. But I am not so sure how to make use of `filter_by_owner` feature.Only with that feature we can go ahead with a real multi tenant  Airflow setup.This is something related to above discussed issues.That's why I just commented here .

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is looking a way that is easy to understand then here's the thing.

Activate you airflow python environment and start `python` shell.
Then with the help of these commands you can easily set a new user in airflow.

```
>>> import airflow
>>> from airflow import models, settings
>>> from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
>>> user = PasswordUser(models.User())
>>> user.username = 'new_user_name'
>>> user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
>>> user.password = 'set_the_password'
>>> session = settings.Session()
>>> session.add(user)
>>> session.commit()
>>> session.close()
>>> exit()
```

If you want to create a admin user you can simply do that by adding `user.superuser = True` It'll do the job.

Comment: Thanks for this. Also can you help on how to set role based access when user is created this way?

Comment: sure, will do it in sometime.

Comment: This is the only way I was able to create users for the experimental API in Airflow 1.10.*, the airflow create_user command didn't work for me.