# Apache Airflow: User creation, access and permissions on DAG

Tags: airflow

I am using airflow (1.8.0) and using web UI I can create a user but it doesn't allow me to set a password. But is it possible via command line to

- create new user with password
- assign role/permissions to a user
- how to limit and manage access of user/group so that they cannot change or trigger someone else's DAG

I have seen apache-airflow (1.10.0) which does have cli feature to create a user with password (https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#create_user), but cannot see anything around setting access level and permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow 1.8.0 doesn't support CLI password creation.

You can create user and set a password as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072563/airflow-user-creation).

Airflow 1.10.0 doesn't allow to manage permissions for a given user, future releases should have this feature.